# Quickly find matrix in another matrix

Tags: java, algorithm

if there is a matrix A[][] of order m and another matrix B[][] of order n such that (m>n) you have to find the occurrence of matrix B[][] in matrix A[][].

```
A[5][5]=
 1,2,3,4,5
 5,4,1,9,7 
 2,1,7,3,4
 6,4,8,2,7
 0,2,4,5,8

B[3][3]=
 1,9,7
 7,3,4
 8,2,7
```

This matrix B exist in A. I can do it by sliding window algo TC O(p^2*n^2) where p = m-n+1. but I want to do this with minimum time complexity.

Comment: stackoverflow does not do homework. Copy your algorythm if you want us to help you on

Comment: @RamonBoza this is not homework. This question was asked in a company's  written exam for which i am going to appear this month. Help me if you can.

Comment: @RamonBoza http://www.vyoms.com/placement-papers/details/nagarro-software-pvt-ltd-chennai-placement-paper-2011-7879.asp check 2nd question. I can do it by brute force. But I want to do it with better time complexity.

Comment: @RamonBoza help me if you can plz.

Comment: Well, on my current company we have blocked access to that kind of resources for "Job Searching" issues xDDDD but no, I wont help you while there is, at least, a duplicate of your question on stackoverflow, just learn to search

Comment: @RamonBoza then you can solve it by brute force only.

Comment: I searched there but answer posted there was bruteforce.

Comment: @BrajeshKumar Please mention that point in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Boyer-Moore string search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) for problems like this:

Compare right to left. In the first row, you compare 3 with 7. 3 doesn't appear in the first row of `B`, so you can move your window to the right by 3 elements. When you start the loop again, the window doesn't fit into the remains of `A`'s first row. This means you could process the first row with 2 compares.

In the next row, you compare 1 with 7. 1 appears in `B`, so you move your window just enough that the 1 in `B` is over the 1 in `A`.

The next level would then be to start comparing with the lower right corner of `B`. That would compare 7 with 7. Since 7 appears three times in `B`, you have to figure out how to move the window efficiently using similar rules as Boyer-Moore.

Answer (score 0):

There is an abstract which I have found on stack-overflow previously . Hope this should give youwhat are the possible algorithms and approaches you could use . [An algorithm for searching for a two dimensional m x m pattern in a two dimensional n x n
text is presented](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.581&rep=rep1&type=pdf).